# How to assign image on specified category and not show the image on other categories

Tags: categories

I want to assign an image to 1 category and want the rest of the categories to be hidden on my home page. I tried this:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo '<img src="http://organeek.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/85.jpg' . $category->cat_ID . '.jpg" alt="' . $category->cat_name . '" />';
}
```

It does not work for me because it shows all the images on all categories. I want to be able to choose only 1 or maybe 2 categories.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to do this inside a post. For this, you can either use [`has_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) or [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) to test if a post belongs to the given category, and if the condition is true, apply your changes

Example:

```
if( has_category('name or I'd or slug of category to test) ) {
     echo '<img src="http://organeek.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/85.jpg' . $category->cat_ID . '.jpg" alt="' . $category->cat_name . '" />';
}else{
    //displays nothing if the post does not belongs to this category
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you complete the code? Im afraid my coding skill is nowhere near advance. In fact, I'm a total newbie. :(

Comment: See my updated code

Comment: Just replace your code with mine

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I seem to be doing something wrong with it as it's not working. Do I need to change anything in it?  Thanks Pieter. I apologize if I'm my question is confusing you. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Where exactly are you using this. Please file an edit to your question and add your current code and details on what exactly do you want to achieve